# Find $ P(X \le 1) $

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, continuous-data

*The random variable X takes values on interval* $ [0, 2] $ , where

$ P( X =1 ) =0.25            $

$ F( x|x<1) = \ x^2 $

$ F( x|x>1) = \ x-1 $

$ E(X) = 1 $

Find $  P(X \le 1) $

My attempt

Since we know that in a continuous distribution  the the probability of getting a specific  random variable x is 0 , so how is it here $ P( X =1 ) =0.25            ? $
Please clarify

Comment: It's not a continuous distribution. You can tell because it has $P(X=1)=0.25$

Comment: @thomaslumley could you please tell how to proceed ?? Please

Comment: $F$ is used for two different conditional CDFs, which is perfectly fine. Each of them is a valid CDF, but for two different variables. That's not a problem.  The question of how they fit together into an overall CDF is one of the constraints that makes the problem soluble

Comment: (1) What tells you this is a continuous distribution?  On the face of it, it could be a mixture of continuous distributions and atoms.  (2) Why do you variously write "$x$" and "$X$"?  Are you trying to make some kind of distinction?  (3) Are you *sure* this formulation is correct?  Pause for a moment to contemplate the facts that your question implies $F(x\mid x\lt 1)$ has a *negative* slope for any $x\lt 0$ and that $F(x\mid x\gt 1)$ grows infinitely large as $x$ grows large.

Comment: @whuber , yes I  realized this isn't continously distributed  , In fact I have calculated the solution,  I will update the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to write down the cdf $F(x)$. There will be an unknown probability $a$ for $x<1$ and an unknown probability $b$ for $x>1$. You get one equation from $F(2)=1$ and another equation from $E[X]=1$, giving two equations in two unknowns to solve